# i want to open a specific file extension on my pc with a specific program

Tags: windows, cmd

What should i write in CMD to add to regs a new key to the file extension ex ".abs" with a special icon .ico to make WINDOWS open all that file type ?  .

I need the cmd code so that i can integrate with my java program ? .

Answer (score 0):

First associate a file type to your extension:

```
assoc .abs=ABSFile
```

Then set up an application to open that file type:

```
ftype ABSFile="C:\Path To Your App\YourExeName.exe" %1 %*
```

For more information, see the [MS TechNet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx), or type `assoc /?` or `ftype /?` from a command prompt.

Comment: it says access denied

Comment: You asked for what you should "write in CMD", and those are the things you should "write". You should be running CMD as an administrator. (Click the Start orb, type in "Command" in the search prompt. When Command Prompt appears in the list, right-click it and choose "Run as Administrator" from the context menu.)